# What is the throughput of Google File System?

Tags: performance, gfs

What is the throughput of Google File System?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

http://labs.google.com/papers/gfs-sosp2003.pdf

Page 11, under 6.1.2 Writes has some figures of throughput. Not sure if that's what you're looking for.

Answer (score 0):

[Here is an article about it](http://storagemojo.com/google-file-system-eval-part-ii/)

FTA:

```
Cluster    A   B
Read Rate - last minute     583 MB/s    380 MB/s
Read Rate - last hour   562 MB/s    384 MB/s
Read Rate - since restart   589 MB/s    49 MB/s
Write Rate - last minute    1 MB/s  101 MB/s
Write Rate - last hour  2 MB/s  117 MB/s
Write Rate - since restart  25 MB/s     13 MB/s
Master Ops - last minute    325 Op/s    533 Op/s
Master Ops - last hour  381 Op/s    518 Op/s
Master Ops - since restart  202 Op/s    347 Op/s
```